# Overlay on Google map using KML

Tags: google-maps

i want to put overlay like http://www.estately.com/CA/Cathedral_City#map this search in google map but I need to have .kml file for that area or region or city which is I don't have.so,if anybody know how can we get .kml file for particular location then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Earth](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/) for that.